# Selenium Webdriver C# Pages with Similar Elements

Tags: c#, class, selenium, webdriver

I have 4 pages with very similar elements and functionalities. However, the elements all have different Ids depending on which page you're on. Currently, I have them constructed as follows (example Class A & Class B). I'd like to refactor this since all of the methods are the same between the 2 classes, but I don't know how to do it since the elements have different Ids (I'm using Page Factory, but I'm open to not using it as well).

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

```
public class A : BaseClass
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ALoginId"]
    public IWebElement Login {get; set;}

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "APassword"]
    public IWebElement Password {get; set;}

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ALoginBtn"]
    public IWebElement LoginBtn {get; set;}

    public void Login()
    {
        Login.SendKeys("username");
        Password.SendKeys("password");
        LoginBtn.Click();
    }
}

public class B : BaseClass
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "BLoginId"]
    public IWebElement Login {get; set;}

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "BPassword"]
    public IWebElement Password {get; set;}

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "BLoginBtn"]
    public IWebElement LoginBtn {get; set;}

    public void Login()
    {
        Login.SendKeys("username");
        Password.SendKeys("password");
        LoginBtn.Click();
    }
}
```

Comment: DO you know a bit of JAVA. I can show it in JAVA.

Comment: I can only say that under
 [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ALoginId"]
    public IWebElement Login {get; set;}

keep Using =  some variable and change Login to element: 
 [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using =  string]
    public IWebElement element {get; set;}


Now pass this element and string through 3 different methods for username, password and loginbutton.

Sorry but i don't know C# . Hope you can relate to it? Do reply . :-)

Comment: I do know Java, so if you can show me an example, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: sorry was late reply. DO see my reply. Feel free to ask if you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If there are similar other fields like name, class you can use that instead of id.

Also here are approach you can use this:

```
public class A : BaseClass
{
    private String loginWindow;

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ALoginId"]
    public IWebElement Login {get; set;}

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "APassword"]
    public IWebElement Password {get; set;}

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ALoginBtn"]
    public IWebElement LoginBtn {get; set;}

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "BLoginId"]
     public IWebElement Loginb {get; set;}

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "BPassword"]
    public IWebElement Passwordb {get; set;}

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "BLoginBtn"]
    public IWebElement LoginBtnb {get; set;}

    public A(Srting loginwindow){
            this.loginWindow; = loginwindow;
    }

    public void Login()
    {
        if(loginwindow.equals("A")) {
            Login.SendKeys("username");
            Password.SendKeys("password");
            LoginBtn.Click();
         }
         elseif(loginwindow.equals("B")){
            Loginb.SendKeys("username");
            Passwordb.SendKeys("password");
            LoginBtnb.Click();
         }
        else{
            throws new Execption("Please provide correct login Window name")
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: It's the same amount of work :( . What I'm trying to shoot for is being able to do the Login functionality once instead of multiple times.

Comment: In above approach you have one login function

Comment: Yes, but I was trying to consolidating having to code the following 3 lines multiple times.{Loginb.SendKeys("username");
            Passwordb.SendKeys("password");
            LoginBtnb.Click();}. The issue is not having multiple methods, but the content of those methods are essentially the same. That's what I am trying to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0):

See the below example..

My test is

```
//MAximize the Screen
driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
//Go to Gmail Login Page
SignInPage SignInPage = WebUtils.GoToSignInPage(driver);
//Sign in to Login page -Send Username 
SignInPage.SendkeysMethodForSignInPAge(driver, By.cssSelector("input[id='Email']") , "kishanpatelllll.8@gmail.com" );
//Click on Next
SignInPage.ClickToLogin(driver, By.cssSelector("input[id='next']"));
//Wait for password field to be visible
SignInPage.WaitForElementTobeVisible(driver, By.cssSelector("input[id='Passwd'][type='password']"));
```

So when i call the method SendkeysMethodForSignInPAge i wont write it in @Test.

See SendkeysMethodForSignInPAge method:

```
public class SignInPage {

  public void SendkeysMethodForSignInPAge(WebDriver driver, By by, String s) {
WebUtils.Sendkeys(driver,by,s);
  }
}
```

So sendkeys is common method which will be used everywhere so it will be in a class calle webutils.

```
public class WebUtils {
   public static void Sendkeys(WebDriver driver, By by, String s) {
        WebElement Element = driver.findElement(by);
        Element.clear();
        Element.sendKeys(s);
  }
}
```

I created a new class and there i defined it. This is basic flow. Hope you can relate this. Reply to me, if your are still stuck. Happy Learning :-)